# CartoDB change public map in real-time with SQL query

Tags: carto, sql, geocoding, api

I'm a data science student working on my capstone project. I'm new to CartoDB and have been playing around with their API a bit but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have created a public map that I will display on my site, but I would like to have the map dynamically change based on a SQL query I send it.

For example, the dataset will contain the entire set of points, but I don't want all of them displayed at once, only I subset that I specify and change (through a select statement) as the user interacts with the program.

Comment: If you want to do anything dynamically with CartoDB, you need to look at cartodb.js and the SQL API in the docs.

Comment: Thank you both for your response. This is very helpful and just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As @John Barça says in the comments, you'll need CartoDB.js.

CartoDB has available a tutorial named "Toggle map view" [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view/) which basically has the basics of what you are trying.

First, it's creating the CartoDB layer:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
  .addTo(map)
  .on('done', function(layer) {
    // change the query for the first layer
    var subLayerOptions = {
      sql: "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places_simple",
      cartocss: "#ne_10m_populated_places_simple{marker-fill: #F84F40; marker-width: 8; marker-line-color: white; marker-line-width: 2; marker-clip: false; marker-allow-overlap: true;}"
    }
```

in which a SQL is added by default, which you can use to determine which points you want to show at the beginning.

And then it adds several buttons in the interface that lets you apply different filters to your map. This will internally change the SQL applied to the layers so that the map is updated. In CartoDB.js, this is performed with the `setSQL` function of a layer, in which you can change the data that is being rendered.

I also have [here](http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/4242013a0f6cdb208d05) another example for filtering with SQL in CartoDB.js. It follows the same idea: create some buttons and when the click event is triggered in them, it calls to `layer.setSQL(sql_here)`. For the record, the whole source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 90%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <button type="button" id="button-basemap1" onclick="setButton1();"> Button 1 (Spain)</button>

    <button type="button" id="button-basemap2" onclick="setButton2();"> Button 2 (Area > 5000)</button>



    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

    <script>


        var dataLayer;

     function setButton1(){
        //filtering by country name
          dataLayer.setSQL("select * from european_countries_e where name = 'Spain'");

          //changing the css too
          dataLayer.setCartoCSS("#european_countries_e{ polygon-fill: #CCC; polygon-opacity: 0.8; line-color: #FFF; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 0.5; } ");

        }

        function setButton2(){
          //filtering by area
          dataLayer.setSQL("select * from european_countries_e where area > 5000");

//changing the css, not mandatory!
 dataLayer.setCartoCSS("#european_countries_e{ polygon-fill: #FFFFB2; polygon-opacity: 0.8; line-color: #FFF; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 0.5; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 1638094] { polygon-fill: #B10026; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 55010] { polygon-fill: #E31A1C; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 34895] { polygon-fill: #FC4E2A; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 12890] { polygon-fill: #FD8D3C; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 10025] { polygon-fill: #FEB24C; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 9150] { polygon-fill: #FED976; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 5592] { polygon-fill: #FFFFB2; } ");
        }
      function main() {

    var map = new L.Map('map', {
      zoomControl: false,
      center: [43, 0],
      zoom: 3

          });

//Adding the basemap here
    var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
}).addTo(map);


cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  //change your username below
  user_name: 'documentation',
  type: 'cartodb',
  sublayers: [{
    //change your sql below
    sql: "SELECT e.cartodb_id, e.area, w.subregion, w.un, e.the_geom, e.the_geom_webmercator FROM european_countries_e e LEFT JOIN world_borders w ON e.iso_2_code = w.iso2",
    //change your cartocss below. you can copy it from the CartoDB Editor and remove the line breaks.
    cartocss: "#european_countries_e{ polygon-fill: #FFFFB2; polygon-opacity: 0.8; line-color: #FFF; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 0.5; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 1638094] { polygon-fill: #B10026; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 55010] { polygon-fill: #E31A1C; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 34895] { polygon-fill: #FC4E2A; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 12890] { polygon-fill: #FD8D3C; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 10025] { polygon-fill: #FEB24C; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 9150] { polygon-fill: #FED976; } #european_countries_e [ area <= 5592] { polygon-fill: #FFFFB2; }"
  }]
})
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer) {

  //here I store the layer in the variable, so that we can query it outside this function
  dataLayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
    })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });


      }
      window.onload = main;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```